# Printing with Gtk.Printing/cairo/pango in gtk2hs - Print-operations in Haskell

Tags: haskell, printing, cairo, pango, gtk2hs

I am currently trying to print files or text (to a printer, not to a terminal etc.) in Haskell with gtk(2hs) using `Graphics.UI.Gtk.Printing`, Cairo and Pango.

Code is the following:

```
op <- printOperationNew
on op printOptBeginPrint $ \context ->   do
                                 set op [ printOperationNPages := 1]
                return ()

on op printOptDrawPage $ \context pages -     do
                     let text = "Hello World"
                     putStrLn $ "Printing :" ++ text

                     --cairo
                     cairoContext<- printContextGetCairoContext context

                     --pango
                     layout<- printContextCreatePangoLayout context

                     layoutSetText layout text

                     let _ = do
                     --inside the Render Monad
                                 showLayout layout
                                 return ()
                     return ()

result <- printOperationRun op PrintOperationActionPrintDialog window
```

This prints an empty page since I set the `printOperationNPages` to 1.
The problem is that cairo does not draw anything. I suppose I have to
connect the `cairoContext` with the pango layout, the proper call to
`showLayout` would actually be `pango_cairo_show_layout (cr, layout);`.

I already discussed this problem on the mailing list for gtk2hs [1].

So if anybody has experience with this, please let me know. I would also be grateful for other - preferable platform-independent - solutions to printing files/text in haskell.

Link to conversation:
[1] http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=27662267

GTK(2hs) in Hackage:
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.12.0

Comment: gtk-cairo: http://projects.haskell.org/gtk2hs/docs/gtk-docs-0.11.0/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Cairo.html

Comment: gtk higher-level printing api: http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/gtk-High-level-Printing-API.html

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use `GtkPrintUnixDialog` instead?
Much simpler to use. Basically you create the `GtkPrintUnixDialog`, Create a `GtkPrintJob`. Set the print to to source file (text,pdf you name it) and then print it out. You can also not show the dialog so that it uses the default print settings on the system.

Comment: I read about it here http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkPrintUnixDialog.html but I haven't found the haskell/gtk2hs equivalent to it. Do you know where it is since it is not in the core library of the Gtk2Hs suite!?